# How to Set "Ignored" / Runtime-Only RealmObject Members in Realm.Net?

Tags: c#, realm, realm-mobile-platform

What's the correct way to use the [Ignored] attribute so that I can instantiate an ImageSource member of the RealmObject "on first get" - while knowing the ImageSource object itself won't be persisted after run-time (see fragment)?

I have the following two members of a RealmObject that aren't working as expected.

```
    ImageSource _favIcon;

    [Ignored]
    public ImageSource FavIcon 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_favIcon==null)
            {
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(FaviconBase64);
                ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
                _favIcon = imageSource;
            }
            return _favIcon;
        }
        
    }
```

This code *works*, in that it runs and I see the ImageSource on screen. But, the "_favIcon = imageSource" statement doesn't stick between calls. The _favIcon field *always* returns null.

I'm trying to avoid re-instatiating images as this is part of a list collection that might get larger over time.

ALSO, being able to reliably instantiate these kinds of "view item / view model" members seems important as I am trying to avoid the horrendous (imho) approach of making view item instances for every model instance. Couldn't [Ignored] work in that context?

Most importantly, why is backing field null every time and how can I fix that?

Thanks, Dave Gerding

Answer (score 3):

Accessing a RealmObject in a collection will return a new instance on every access. For example:

```
var foos = realm.All<Foo>();
var foo1 = foos.ElementAt(0);
var foo2 = foos.ElementAt(0);

Assert.False(ReferenceEquals(foo1, foo2));
```

Even though `foo1` and `foo2` point to the same persisted object, they are not the same managed (c#) instance. This means that if you set an in-memory property on `foo1`, that won't be set on `foo2`. If you access the same instance though, you should not be seeing the ignored fields be nullified:

```
var foo = foos.ElementAt(0);
foo.FavIcon; // Will set _favIcon to something on the foo instance

foos.ElementAt(0).FavIcon; // _favIcon is null because that's different from foo.

foo.FavIcon; // _favIcon is still not null because you're referencing the same foo.
```

Generally, Realm (and Realm Sync) is not a perfect fit for storing binary data. A better approach would be to store the image url in your Realm models and use a 3rd party library, such as [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) to handle downloading and caching the images. The benefits of such an approach are:

- You get parallel downloads from sources that are optimized for delivering binary data (such as S3 or a CDN).
- You can have multiple sizes of the same image, thus optimizing downloads for different form factors.
- The library is handling in-memory and disk caching for you, so you won't have to hit the disk for commonly accessed images and you won't have to monitor memory usage yourself.
- The Realm database is much smaller in size which means it will perform better.